# How to overlay a label and a cell frame?

Tags: front-end, labeling, customization, cells

How to put a label on a cell frame or align cell frame label with parent's cell frame?

Like that:

[image]

I did it but the solution is ugly not very responsive. I will post it unless better solutions appear.

Here is a starting point:

```
CellPrint[
  Cell["Test content", "Text"
  , CellFrame -> True
  , CellFrameLabelMargins -> 0
  , CellFrameLabels -> { {None, None}, {None, Cell[
      "Test label", "Text"
    , CellFrame -> 2
    , CellMargins -> 0
    , CellFrameMargins -> {{50, 50}, {5, 5}}
    ] }}
  ]
]
```

One can propose completely different approach of course.

Requirements in such case are:

- such label needs to work from a stylesheet
- label and the parent cell should give an impression of being the same element, one can't delete one of them etc.
- it needs to work well on Win and Mac
- the label is not editable and the cell work as a regular cell
- should work well when Magnification changes

Comment: Unfortunately there is not a `CellFrameLabelAlignment` option

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch a lot of similar problems could be solved if there was `CellDisplayFunction` or something similar.

Comment: If you've only got a certain set of labels/appearances you want you can also try nine-patch images

Answer (score 1):

#### Fun example:

Here's both a header and a footer using Mathematica's built in nine-patch images:

```
CellPrint[
 Cell[ExampleData[{"Text", "LoremIpsum"}]~Snippet~5, "Text",
  CellFrame -> {{1, 1}, {1, 1}},
  FrontEnd`CellFrameStyle -> GrayLevel[.8],
  CellFrameLabelMargins -> {{0, 0}, {-1, -1}},
  CellFrameLabels -> {
    {None, None},
    {
     ToBoxes@
      Panel["Cell footer",
       BaseStyle -> {
         (*turn this into an actual stylesheet style for better \
customizability/inheritance*)
         "Text",
         FontColor -> Hue[0, .5, .5],
         ShowStringCharacters -> False,
         PanelBoxOptions -> {
           FrameStyle -> Black,
           ImageSize -> {
             FEPrivate`Switch[
               FEPrivate`$OperatingSystem,
               "MacOSX", 18,
               "Window", 0,
               "Linux", 0,
               _, 0] + Scaled[1],
             Automatic
             },
           FrameMargins -> {{10, 10}, {5, 5}},
           Appearance -> {
             "Default" ->

              FrontEnd`FileName[{"Ribbons", "Common"}, 
               "ContentAreaGradient.9.png"]
             }
           }
         }
       ],
     ToBoxes@
      Panel["Cell header",
       BaseStyle -> {
         (*turn this into an actual stylesheet style for better \
customizability/inheritance*)
         "Text",
         FontColor -> Hue[0, .5, .5],
         ShowStringCharacters -> False,
         PanelBoxOptions -> {
           Appearance -> {
             "Default" ->

              FrontEnd`FileName[{"Dialogs", "CloudDialogs"}, 
               "AttachedCell.9.png"]
             },
           ImageSize -> {
             FEPrivate`Switch[
               FEPrivate`$OperatingSystem,
               "MacOSX", 18,
               "Window", 0,
               "Linux", 0,
               _, 0] + Scaled[1],
             Automatic
             },
           FrameMargins -> {{10, 10}, {5, 5}}
           }
         }
       ]
     }
    }
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

## Original

Here are two options:

### Boxes

This one works really simply:

```
CellPrint[
 Cell["Test content",
  "Text",
  CellFrame -> True,
  CellFrameLabelMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, -2}},
  CellSize -> {Automatic, 100},
  CellFrameLabels -> {
    {None, None},
    {None,
     ToBoxes@
      Framed["asdasd", 
       BaseStyle -> {
         (* 
         turn this into an actual stylesheet style for better customizability/inheritance *)
         "Text",
         FontColor -> White, 
         ShowStringCharacters -> False,
         FrameBoxOptions -> {
           FrameStyle -> Black,
           ImageSize ->
            {
             FEPrivate`Switch[
               FEPrivate`$OperatingSystem, 
               "MacOSX", 18,
               "Window", 0(* Windows fudge factor *),
               "Linux",  0(* Linux  fudge factor *),
               _, 0
               ] + Scaled[1], 
             Automatic
             },
           FrameMargins -> {{10, 10}, {5, 5}},
           Background -> Blue
           }
         }
       ]
     }
    }
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

Outside of the weird 18 pixel fudge factor which it turns out has nothing to do with the `CellMargins`, `"VerticalScrollBar"`, `CellBracketOptions`, `ShowCellBracket` or any of the other things I tested this one takes the cake for convenience.

If you substitute in `PanelBox` you can leverage the paneled appearance really nicely. Here's what `Panel` looks like with `FrameBoxOptions` changed to `PanelBoxOptions` and the addition of

```
Appearance -> {
  "Default" ->
   FrontEnd`FileName[{"Ribbons", "Common"}, 
    "ContentAreaGradient.9.png"]
  }
```

[image]

### Cells

This is much trickier but here's what I got:

```
CellPrint[
 Cell["Test content", "Text",
  CellFrame -> True,
  CellFrameLabelMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}},
  CellMargins -> {{25, 55}, {5, 5}},
  CellBracketOptions -> {
    "Widths" -> {0, 15},
    "OverlapContent" -> True
    },
  CellFrameLabels ->
   {
    {None, None},
    {None,
     Cell["Test label", "Text",
      Background -> Blue,
      FontColor -> White,
      CellFrame -> {{1, 1}, {0, 1}},
      CellMargins -> 0,
      CellFrameMargins -> {{50, 50}, {5, 5}},
      CellSize -> {
        FEPrivate`Part[

           FrontEnd`AbsoluteCurrentValue[
            FrontEnd`EvaluationNotebook[], WindowSize],
           1
           ]/
          FrontEnd`AbsoluteCurrentValue[
           FrontEnd`EvaluationNotebook[], Magnification] - (
          FEPrivate`Part[
            FrontEnd`AbsoluteCurrentValue[
             FrontEnd`ParentCell@FrontEnd`EvaluationCell[], 
             CellMargins
             ],
            1, 1
            ] +
           FEPrivate`Part[
            FrontEnd`AbsoluteCurrentValue[
             FrontEnd`ParentCell@FrontEnd`EvaluationCell[], 
             CellMargins
             ],
            1, 2
            ] +
           (* dunno where the fudge factors here are coming from...*)

                      FEPrivate`If[
            FEPrivate`SameQ[
             FrontEnd`AbsoluteCurrentValue[
              FrontEnd`ParentCell@FrontEnd`EvaluationCell[], 
              {CellBracketOptions, "OverlapContent"}
              ],
             True
             ],
            0,
            FEPrivate`Part[
              FrontEnd`AbsoluteCurrentValue[
               FrontEnd`ParentCell@FrontEnd`EvaluationCell[], 
               {CellBracketOptions, "Widths"}
               ],
              2
              ] +

             3/FrontEnd`AbsoluteCurrentValue[
               FrontEnd`EvaluationNotebook[], Magnification]
            ] +
           FEPrivate`If[
            FEPrivate`MemberQ[
             FrontEnd`AbsoluteCurrentValue[
              FrontEnd`EvaluationNotebook[], 
              WindowElements
              ],
             "VerticalScrollBar"
             ],

            15/FrontEnd`AbsoluteCurrentValue[
              FrontEnd`EvaluationNotebook[], Magnification],
            0
            ]
          ),
        Automatic
        }
      ]
     }
    }
  ]
 ]
```

You'll notice there are many more fudge factor here to tweak, but it seems to again handle the many settings I've tried and it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [`CellLabel`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellLabel) instead of [`CellFrameLabels`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellFrameLabels). The tricky part is that [`CellLabel`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellLabel) doesn't seem to be settable from a stylesheet. To workaround that issue, you can use [`CellDynamicExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellDynamicExpression). Also, the default font for the "CellLabel" style seems to get clipped at the top, so I changed the font. I think the following modification to the "Text" style does what you want:

```
Cell[StyleData["Text"],
    CellDynamicExpression :> SetOptions[
        EvaluationCell[],
        {CellLabel->"Test label", CellDynamicExpression :> None}
    ],
    CellLabelStyle->Directive["CellLabel", FontFamily->"Verdana"],
    CellMargins -> {{66,10},{7,8}},
    CellLabelMargins -> {{66,0},{0,0}},
    CellLabelPositioning -> Above,
    CellLabelAutoDelete -> False,
    CellFrame -> True
]
```

Example:

[image]

If you need the label framed as well, then I don't think you can use this approach.